# When is the fullcalendar-react component scheduled to be production ready?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

The documentation for fullcalendar-react still says its in beta. We are considering to use this in our project. I want to understand when this is planned to be a stable RTM release so that I can consider whether this will help us in the production builds of future.

Comment: You'd be better to ask on the fullCalendar GitHub page. As far as I know, no-one who deals with fullCalendar on this site is directly involved in the project

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for information about the progress of a project, rather than an actual programming issue.